# Is there a way to show numbers better formatted in javascript? (with commas etc..)

Tags: javascript, format, numbers, tofixed

If I use toLocaleString at the end of each line, I get 1 number formatted, and all other numbers get value NaN.

```
let cta = document.getElementById('cnt');

cta.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let deviza = document.getElementById('deviza').value;
  let kurs = document.getElementById('kurs').value;
  let prihod = document.getElementById('prihod').value = (deviza * kurs).toFixed(2);
  let trosak = document.getElementById('trosak').value = (prihod * .2).toFixed(2);
  let osnovica = document.getElementById('osnovica').value = (parseFloat(prihod) - parseFloat(trosak)).toFixed(2);
  let porez = document.getElementById('porez').value = (osnovica * .2).toFixed(2);
  let pio = document.getElementById('pio').value = (osnovica * .255).toFixed(2);
  let zdrav = document.getElementById('zdrav').value = (osnovica * .103).toFixed(2);
  let totalPorez = document.getElementById('totalPorez').value = (parseFloat(porez) + parseFloat(pio) + parseFloat(zdrav)).toFixed(2);
  let netoPrihod = document.getElementById('netoPrihod').value = (parseFloat(prihod) - parseFloat(totalPorez)).toFixed(2);
})
```

Comment: Treat the value and what's displayed as two separate things. At the moment your business logic is very coupled with how the numbers actually get showed, which is poor architecture.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for taking time to reply. Appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/), library that is rich in number formatting options, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer